# Slider or Carousel of images backwards doesn't work

Tags: javascript, slider, carousel, slideshow

Good day

I'm making a slider in JavaScript automatically and manually on my own, I don't want to use jQuery or Bootstrap libraries.

To change from one image to another, use the arrows or circles (I have not made them functional yet); The circles are colored as the image advances, it works perfect when moving images forward, but when moving them backwards (by clicking the back arrow) it does not advance continuously, it only stays frozen for a few seconds or more until which then changes to the back image.

JavaScript Code:

```
let index =0;
let aux_index = 0
let aux_circle =0
const images = ['Image1.jpg','Image2.jpg', 'Image3.jpg']
let index_circle = images.length -1
let image_selected = document.getElementById('img_selected')
const circleSection = document.querySelectorAll(".circle-section")
var timeR = setInterval(next, 4000)


image_selected.src = images[0]
circleSection[index_circle].classList.add('current')
index++;
index_circle--;

function next(){
        image_selected.src = images[index]

        for (var i =0 ; i < circleSection.length ; i++) {
            circleSection[i].classList.remove('current')
        }
        circleSection[index_circle].classList.add('current')
        
        index++;
        aux_index = index-1
        aux_circle = index_circle +1
        if (index == images.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        index_circle--
        if(index_circle < 0){
            index_circle = images.length - 1

        }   
}

function back(){

    if ((aux_index-1) <0) {
        aux_index = images.length
    }
    if (aux_circle == images.length) {
        aux_circle = 0
    }
    image_selected.src = images[aux_index - 1]
    for (var i =0 ; i < circleSection.length ; i++) {
        circleSection[i].classList.remove('current')
    }
    circleSection[aux_circle].classList.add('current')
    index--
    index_circle++
    if (index_circle == images.length ) {
        index_circle =0
    }
    if (index <0) {
        index = images.length -1
    }                  
}
btn_right.addEventListener('click', function(){
    next();
    clearInterval(timeR);
    timeR = setInterval(next, 4000);
})

btn_left.addEventListener('click', function(){
    back()
    clearInterval(timeR);
    timeR = setInterval(next, 4000);
})
```

PART OF HTML CODE:

```
 <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider" id="slider_id">
        <div class="slider-section" >
            <img class="img_slider" id="img_selected" src="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="btn_right" class="btn_slider">&#62</div>
    <div id="btn_left" class="btn_slider">&#60</div>
</div>
<ul id="circles">
    <li class="circle-section" id="1"></li>
    <li class="circle-section" id="2"></li>
    <li class="circle-section" id="3"></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want i have a full slider code, it is very close to what you are looking for.

Comment: @ Mister Jojo I already made it, but it would not be bad to see your slider.

Comment: added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating your `aux_index`.

Add this before you subtract from your index.

```
aux_index = index+1
```

```js
let index =0;
let aux_index = 0
let aux_circle = 0
const images = ['https://placekitten.com/g/200/300','https://placekitten.com/200/300', 'https://placekitten.com/g/400/300']
let index_circle = images.length -1
let image_selected = document.getElementById('img_selected')
const circleSection = document.querySelectorAll(".circle-section")
var timeR = setInterval(next, 4000)


image_selected.src = images[0]
circleSection[index_circle].classList.add('current')
index++;
index_circle--;

function next(){
        image_selected.src = images[index]

        for (var i =0 ; i < circleSection.length ; i++) {
            circleSection[i].classList.remove('current')
        }
        circleSection[index_circle].classList.add('current')
        
        index++;
        aux_index = index-1
        aux_circle = index_circle +1
        if (index == images.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        index_circle--
        if(index_circle < 0){
            index_circle = images.length - 1

        }   
}

function back(){
    if ((aux_index-1) <0) {
        aux_index = images.length
    }
    if (aux_circle == images.length) {
        aux_circle = 0
    }
    image_selected.src = images[aux_index - 1]
    for (var i =0 ; i < circleSection.length ; i++) {
        circleSection[i].classList.remove('current')
    }
    circleSection[aux_circle].classList.add('current')
    aux_index = index+1
    index--
    index_circle++
    if (index_circle == images.length ) {
        index_circle =0
    }
    if (index <0) {
        index = images.length -1
    }                  
}
btn_right.addEventListener('click', function(){
    next();
    clearInterval(timeR);
    timeR = setInterval(next, 4000);
})

btn_left.addEventListener('click', function(){
    back()
    clearInterval(timeR);
    timeR = setInterval(next, 4000);
})
```

```html
 <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider" id="slider_id">
        <div class="slider-section" >
            <img class="img_slider" id="img_selected" src="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="btn_right" class="btn_slider">&#62</div>
    <div id="btn_left" class="btn_slider">&#60</div>
</div>
<ul id="circles">
    <li class="circle-section" id="1"></li>
    <li class="circle-section" id="2"></li>
    <li class="circle-section" id="3"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It only remains to add this: aux_circle=index_circle, so that the circles are colored. But it worked for me Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

*In the comments here:*

> -- if you want i have a full slider code, it is very close to what you are looking for. – Mister Jojo
> -- I already made it, but it would not be bad to see your slider. – Jorge Rojas C.

here it is:

```js
const
  imgSlider = document.querySelector('#imgSlider')
, btTimer   = document.querySelector('#timer-bt')
, bullets   = document.querySelector('#bullets')
  ;
const imgMover = (function()
  {
  var 
    currentImg = 0
  , sel_bullet = 'current' // 'timer-action'
  , timerMod   = false
    ;
  const
    bullet_list = [...document.querySelectorAll('#imgSlider > figure')].map((fig,i)=>
      {
      if (i) fig.classList.add('onRight')
      let sp = document.createElement('span')
      if (i===currentImg) sp.className = sel_bullet
      sp.dataset.ref = i
      sp.innerHTML = `
        <svg viewbox="0 0 90 90">
          <circle class="progress" cx="46" cy="46" r="33" ></circle>
          <circle class="bull" cx="46" cy="46" r="23" ></circle>
        </svg>`
      bullets.appendChild(sp)
      return sp
      })
  , imgCount = bullet_list.length
    ;
  setTimeout(() => { btTimer.click() }, 100)

  return {
    setTimerMod( bool )
      {
      if (timerMod != bool)
        {
        let newCL = bool ? 'timer-action' : 'current' 
        bullet_list[currentImg].classList.add(newCL)
        bullet_list[currentImg].classList.remove(sel_bullet)
        sel_bullet = newCL 
        timerMod   = bool
        btTimer.classList.toggle('onRun',timerMod) 
        }
      }
  , movTo(imgMov, targetImg = 0)
      {
      if ( imgMov === 0 )
        { imgMov = targetImg - currentImg }
      else
        { targetImg = (currentImg +imgMov +imgCount) % imgCount }

      let inPosCl  = (imgMov > 0) ? 'onRight'   : 'onLeft'
        , outPosCl = (imgMov > 0) ? 'hideLeft' : 'hideRight'
        , imgOut   = currentImg
        ;
      currentImg = targetImg

      if (targetImg !== imgOut)
        {
        bullet_list.forEach((bull,indx) => bull.classList.toggle(sel_bullet, (indx===currentImg)))
        
        imgSlider.querySelector(`figure:nth-of-type(${targetImg +1})`).className = inPosCl
        setTimeout(() =>
          {
          imgSlider.querySelector(`figure:nth-of-type(${imgOut +1})`).className = outPosCl
          imgSlider.querySelector(`figure:nth-of-type(${targetImg +1})`).className = 'onShow'
          },20);
  } } } }
)()
movNext.onclick = () =>
  {
  imgMover.setTimerMod( false )
  imgMover.movTo(+1) 
  }
movPrev.onclick = () =>
  {
  imgMover.setTimerMod( false )
  imgMover.movTo(-1) 
  }
bullets.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  let bull = target.closest('span[data-ref]')
  if (!bull) return
  imgMover.setTimerMod( false )
  imgMover.movTo(0, +bull.dataset.ref)
  }
btTimer.onclick = () =>
  {
  imgMover.setTimerMod( btTimer.classList.toggle('onRun') )
  }
bullets.ontransitionend = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('circle.progress')) return
  imgMover.movTo(+1) 
  }
```

```css
:root {
  --timer-delay : 3s;
  --szH         : 300px;
  --szW         : 400px;
  --img-trans   : 1s;
  }
#imgSlider {
  display    : block;
  width      : var(--szW);
  height     : var(--szH);
  overflow   : hidden;
  position   : relative;
  }
#imgSlider figure {
  position : absolute;
  display  : block;
  width    : var(--szW);
  height   : var(--szH);
  left     : 0;
  margin   : 0;
  padding  : 0;
  }
#imgSlider figure figcaption {
  display          : block;
  width            : calc( var(--szW) - 80px );
  height           : 50px;
  text-align       : center;
  transform        : translate(40px, -60px);
  background-color : #00000080;
  color            : crimson;
  font-size        : 2em;
  font-weight      : bold;
  line-height      : 50px;
  border-radius    : 20px;
  }
#imgSlider figure.hideLeft {
  left       : calc( var(--szW) * -1 );
  transition : var(--img-trans);
  }
#imgSlider figure.hideRight {
  left       : var(--szW);
  transition : var(--img-trans);
  }
#imgSlider figure.onLeft {
  left      : calc( var(--szW) * -1 );
  }
#imgSlider figure.onRight {
  left      : var(--szW);
  }
#imgSlider figure.onShow {
  left       : 0;
  transition : var(--img-trans);
  }
#bullets {
  position   : relative;
  margin     : 1em;
  }
#bullets span {
  width      : auto;
  height     : auto;
  margin     : 0;
  background : 0;
  }
#bullets svg {
  transform  : scale(.8) rotate(-90deg);
  transition : transform .3s ease;
  width      : 30px;
  height     : 30px;
  }
#bullets span.current svg,
#bullets span.timer-action svg {
  transform  : scale(1) rotate(-90deg);
  }
#bullets circle {
  stroke-dasharray  : 440;
  }
#bullets circle.progress {
  stroke            : #344770;;
  stroke-width      : 6;
  fill              : none;
  stroke-dashoffset : 440;
  }
#bullets span.timer-action circle.progress {
  stroke-dashoffset : 220;
  transition        : linear var(--timer-delay) stroke-dashoffset;
  }
#bullets circle.bull                   { fill: #cccccc; }
#bullets span:hover circle.bull        { fill: #5d83d6; }
#bullets span.current circle.bull, 
#bullets span.timer-action circle.bull { fill: #08075c; }

button {
  width         : 2em;
  font-size     : 1.3em;
  border-radius : 50%;
  font-family   : Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  }
button#timer-bt:before       { content : '\1405'; }
button#timer-bt.onRun:before { content : '\2161'; }
```

```html
<div id="imgSlider">
  <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/102/400/300" ><figcaption>slider 1</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/146/400/300" ><figcaption>slider 2</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/275/400/300" ><figcaption>slider 3</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/106/400/300" ><figcaption>slider 4</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/133/400/300" ><figcaption>slider 5</figcaption></figure>
  <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/135/400/300" ><figcaption>slider 6</figcaption></figure>
</div>
<div id="bullets"></div>
<button id="movPrev"  title="previous"         >&LT;</button>
<button id="timer-bt" title="timer play/pause" ></button>
<button id="movNext"  title="next"             >&GT;</button>
```

Comment: @JorgeRojasC. no comments about my code ?